# NG05100:Providers from`BrowserModule` have already been loaded.If you need access to common directives such as NgIf import the `CommonModule` instead

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-providers, angular17

I am getting above error even though I have imported CommonModule in all related modules having NgIf or NgFor and BrowserModule is only imported once in app.module.ts

[image: app.module.ts]

What else I can do please help me.
Angular version
[image]
Error Message
[image]

Also I have migrated my project to be standalone component still it is not resolved as I read some solution like this also.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

My issue was because I was importing the `[BrowserAnimationsModule]`(https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/platform-browser/animations/src/module.ts#L34) which is re-exporting `BrowserModule`.

I removed it from `app.module` and imported it where I needed it.

BTW if you are using Angular 17 with [`bootstrapApplication`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/bootstrapApplication), you can remove this module and use `provideAnimations()`.

Answer (score -1):

The `BrowserAnimationModule` also pulls the `BrowserModule.`

Remove the `BrowserModule` and you should be fine !

Comment: I removed BrowserModule but still it is giving the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue in angular v.17.

in `app.config.ts` file I added `provideAnimations()` in providers.It's not related to `CommonModule`.

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations()],
};
```